# Is there a tensorflow implementation of EnCTC

Tags: tensorflow, ctc

Is there a tensorflow implementation of EnCTC described in Connectionist Temporal Classification with Maximum Entropy Regularization?

Comment: As of April 2021, no.

Comment: I added a feature request: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48614